# How does Pyspark parallelize process of reading a 1TB file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have a 1 TB file kept on AWS S3. How does Pyspark read the file or more specifically how does the task of reading the file is split across various worker nodes ?

Sample Code to read the file

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 
sc =  SparkSession.builder.appName('test-project').getOrCreate()
temp = sc.read.csv('s3 file path to csv')
```

1. Would temp dataframe be held in the driver node where the SparkSession is running ?
2. Is temp kept in memory or on the disk once the read process is complete
3. is it possible to breakdown the read process to multiple nodes for the above sample csv file

Comment: it depends on if the file is splittable or not.  Like, some of the compression algorithms doesn't support splitting (gzip by default), so in this case file will be read only by one process without parallelization

Comment: its not a zipped file , its an unzipped csv file